# Error while using Convolutional layers on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Can I use Convolutional layers of keras without gpu support? I am getting errors when I use it on Colab with runtime as None.
My code looks like this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv1D(1,5, name='conv1', padding="same", activation='relu',data_format="channels_first", input_shape=(1,2048)))
# model.add(layers.LSTM(5, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
#model.summary()
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

x_train = train_value
y_train = train_label
x_test = test_value
y_test = test_label
print(np.shape(x_train)) #shape of x train is (4459, 1, 2048)
print(np.shape(x_test)) #shape of test is (1340,1,2048)

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=100,
          epochs=30, 
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test)

          )
```

It is running fine on GPU but gives following error on CPU:

> InvalidArgumentError: Conv2DCustomBackpropFilterOp only supports NHWC.
>      [[{{node
>   training/SGD/gradients/gradients/conv1/conv1d_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter}}]]
>
> UnimplementedError: The Conv2D op currently only supports the NHWC
>   tensor format on the CPU. The op was given the format: NCHW    [[{{node
>   conv1_1/conv1d}}]]

I have figured out that the problem is with the format of Input Data. My input data are vectors of size (1,2048). Can you please guide me on how to convert these vectors to NHWC format?
I would really appreciate it, if someone can clear this up for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example with full error traceback, otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @xdurch0 edited. Please check again

Comment: Why are you setting the data_format in the Conv1D layer? Its not something you should really fiddle with, and its the source of your problem

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It is increasing my accuracy. Removing it makes my model prediction worst!

Comment: Why accuracy is so much different on GPU vs CPU?

Comment: That makes no sense, its more of a problem of incorrectly formatting data, you should not fiddle with the data_format, just swap the channels and width dimensions in your data.

Comment: My data are vectors of size (1x2048) how can there be channels in them? Please guide me exactly in code how can I do that! Thanks

Comment: What do the dimension in the vector mean? And how exactly do you want to apply convolution on them?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro They are n number of vectors each of size (1,2048). I want to apply a temporal convolution, to retrieve time series information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the Keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/)

> data_format: A string, one of "channels_last" (default) or "channels_first". The ordering of the dimensions in the inputs. "channels_last" corresponds to inputs with shape (batch, steps, channels) (default format for temporal data in Keras) while "channels_first" corresponds to inputs with shape (batch, channels, steps)

Now Keras in TensorFlow appears to implement `Conv1D` in terms of a `Conv2D` operator - basically forming an "image" with 1 row, `W` columns, and then your `C` "channels". That's why your getting error messages about image shapes when you don't have image data.

In the docs above "channels" are the number of data items per time step (e.g. perhaps you have 5 sensor readings at each time step so you'd have 5 channels). From your answers above I believe you're passing tensors with shape `(n, 1, 2048)` where `n` is your batch size. So, with `channels_last` TensorFlow thinks that means you have `n` examples in your batch each with a sequence length of `1` and `2048` data items per time step - that is only a single time step with 2048 data items per observation (e.g. 2048 sensor readings taken at each time step) in which case the convolution won't be doing a convolution - it'd be equivalent to a single dense layer taking all 2048 numbers as input.

I think in reality you have only a single data item per time step and you have 2048 time steps. That explains why passing `channels_first` improves your accuracy - now TensorFlow understand that your data represents 1 data item samples 2048 times and it can do a convolution over that data.

To fix you can just `tf.reshape(t, (1, 2048, 1))` - and remove the `channels_first` (that code assumes you're doing batches of size 1 and your tensor is named `t`). Now it's in the format `(n, s, 1)` where `n` is the batch size (`1` here), `s` is the number of time steps (2048), and `1` indicates one data point per time step. You can now run the same model on the GPU or CPU.

Comment: my train_value = (4459,1,2048) and train_labels are (4459,6) as they are one-hot encoded. Will I have to reshape it to (4459,2048,1)? what will than my input shape parameter will get in the Conv1D?

Comment: correct, reshape it to `(4459,2048,1)`. That corresponds to `channels_last` so you can pass that as the `data_format`. Since that's also the default shape you can just remove the `data_format` argument entirely.

Comment: Will it affect my idea of temporal convolution. Basically my aim was to apply a 1d convolution filter of size 5. It had to concatenate learn a convolutional filter from  5 vectors of size 2048 in each iteration.

Comment: It is throwing error. Telling me to change my input shape is incorrect as it should be (2048,1)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by concatenating 5 vectors of size 2048. As for getting an error, I don't think you've provided enough code for me to understand what you're doing. You're loading some data. At some point it has shape (2048, 1). Above you say you have 4459 such examples in each batch (crazy big batch size). I don't know where/how you load the data or where/how you reshape.

Comment: Sorry.  I have clarified my Question once again. Please check the edit. and tell me specifically what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Given the clarification I think you want `x_train = tf.reshape(x_train, (4459, 2048, 1))` before passing it to `model.fit` and you want to remove `data_format="channels_first"` from your `layers.Conv1D` call.

Comment: Still getting Error when checking input: expected conv1_input to have shape (1, 2048) but got array with shape (2048, 1)

Comment: oh, that's because you have to change the `input_shape` in the `Conv1D` call as well so it matches your reshaped data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208789/discussion-between-rehan-and-oliver-dain).

Comment: This is reducing my accuracy.