# Group convolution in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, convolution

I created a simple neural network for understanding how group convolutions can reduce the number of parameters. But when I use the **groups** parameter in the second convolution layer, I am getting an unimplemented error. However, when **groups** parameter is not used, everything works fine. Why when using **groups** parameter, it throws unimplemented error? Does that mean group convolution is not available in keras api?

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D,Reshape,MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np

num_classes = 10

a = np.random.randint(low=0,high=255,size=(100,28,28,1))

b = np.random.randint(low=0,high=10,size=(100,7,7))

a = a.astype('float32')

a = a/255


X_train, Y_train = a[:80], b[:80]

X_test, Y_test = a[80:], b[80:]

num_classes=10

Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes)
Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, num_classes)

# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=(28,28,1),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3,3),groups=4,input_shape=(28,28,1),padding='same'))
# model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
# model.add(Reshape(target_shape=(10,)))
         
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=250, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)

# model.save_weights("model.h5")


# # Test the model after training
# test_results = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=1)
# print(f'Test results - Loss: {test_results[0]} - Accuracy: {test_results[1]}%')
```

**Error**

```
UnimplementedError:  Fused conv implementation does not support grouped convolutions for now.
     [[node sequential_38/conv2d_37/BiasAdd (defined at <ipython-input-42-e7c1c931a421>:50) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_8596]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: There is no problem with your code. What's your `tf` version?

Comment: @M.Innat tensorflow:2.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jvKjz8CuZQpFGnUpQsA67zYMAeLiE327?usp=sharing) is the colab file for your code. According to the doc

> A positive integer specifying the number of groups in which the input is split along the channel axis. Each group is convolved separately with filters / groups filters. The output is the concatenation of all the groups results along the channel axis. Input channels and filters must both be divisible by groups.

In your code, I found no conflict with that. It should work. Otherwise, it may issue with something else.

Comment: Thank you. I checked your colab file and it worked without issue. Can you check this colab file [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1liN5PRoThFy1K2-jzMJC2D-lkmCMRbaw?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes, no issue. It's running.

Comment: I think it will not update on your side, [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sWq19XDbFoVA9LFB12bslBwrw1vSzzCR?usp=sharing) I checked again by copying your notebook.

Comment: Thanks M.Innat. The code works fine on GPU runtime and throws error on CPU runtime. Can you check this with CPU runtime on colab

Comment: Yes, now I get the same error in CPU mode and I don't have an exact answer on that now. You may raise an issue on GitHub on that. However, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468512/error-while-using-convolutional-layers-on-cpu) also.